# How do I access an object property/key in Java (Android) by string variable

Tags: java, android, object, properties, key

**EDIT:** To clarify, I want to get the **value** of the property, not the name of the property. I know the name of the property but I need to access the property via a string containing the property name. I am importing an API, that has additional vendor properties (not part of the standard documentation or SDK) which I am trying to access the value of.

Hi I have the following code

```
                String mykey = "SCALER_AVAILABLE_STREAM_CONFIGURATIONS";
                 mystring.append(characteristics[mykey]);
```

characteristics is a type of object CameraCharacteristics, and SCALER_AVAILABLE_STREAM_CONFIGURATIONS is a property of it. How do I access a property of an object by a variable in Java (using Android Stuidio)?

Log:

```
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
                         mystring.append(characteristics[mykey]);
```

The tooltip info gives me `Array type expected; found: 'android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics'`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the get declared field function

```
     ClassDemo c = new ClassDemo();
     Class cls = c.getClass();

     // field long l
     Field lVal  = cls.getDeclaredField("l")
```

> Returns a Field object that reflects the specified declared field of
> the class or interface represented by this Class object. The name
> parameter is a String that specifies the simple name of the desired
> field.

Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)

Comment: I tried this, but it is an unresolved symbol, there is a provided method in the API public T get (Key<T> key) but I havent been able to get that to work.

Comment: Also correct me if I am wrong but it looks like getDeclaredFields returns the **name** of the property. I know the name of the property. I want to get the value of the property. For example, I want to know the value of myobject.myproperty but by string, eg;

<code>
String propertylookup = "isEnabled";
boolean value = myobject[propertookup]; //have also tried myobject.get(myobjectClass.Key<T>propertylookup>
if (value == true){
//stuff
}</code>